# How do I get UI reference from AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to learn MultiThreading in android although my code works fine when I print the data on Logcat window but my app crashes and gives me a null point exception whenever I try to update a component from the asynctask.

It gives me the following error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.shivam.asynctasks.MainActivity.logm(MainActivity.java:41)
```

Line 41

```
textView.append(message + "\n");
```

My Code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button ;
    TextView textView;
    String TAG = "MyTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.TextView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String TAG ="MyTag";
                Log.d(TAG,"OnClick Thread Started");

                MyTask mytask =new MyTask();
                mytask.execute("Red","Black","Yellow","Blue","Orange");
            }
        });
    }


    public void logm(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, message);
        textView.append(message + "\n");
    }
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String TAG = "MyTag";

        for (String value :
                strings) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "do in Background  : "+value);
            publishProgress(value);

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         MainActivity mainActivity =new MainActivity();

        for (String color : values) {

            mainActivity.logm(color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new activity with `new MainActivity()`... You need to access the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your activity not create new one. Here you can see.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button ;
    TextView textView;
    String TAG = "MyTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.TextView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String TAG ="MyTag";
                Log.d(TAG,"OnClick Thread Started");

                MyTask mytask =new MyTask(this);
                mytask.execute("Red","Black","Yellow","Blue","Orange");
            }
        });
    }


    public void logm(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, message);
        textView.append(message + "\n");
    }
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityRef;
    public MyTask(MainActivity activity){
        mainActivityRef = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String TAG = "MyTag";

        for (String value :
                strings) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "do in Background  : "+value);
            publishProgress(value);

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityRef.get();

        for (String color : values) {
            mainActivity.logm(color);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code worked but it is giving me a warning  This field leaks a context object  here          class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
MainActivity mainActivity;//on this line can you explain why it's showing this warning

Comment: Because when asynctask update progress, activity can be already destroyed. We shouldn't keep context reference. We need to use weakreference in these cases, please take a look at updated answer

Comment: Just one more thing I tried using    mainActivityRef.logm(color); to access the method but wasn't able to to do so //cannot reslove method logm(java.lang.string).

Comment: You need to get the reference. You can do it like this: mainActivityRef.get().logm(color);

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the you are creating the instance of the mainactivity class again inside the onProgressUpdate() method whose textView is not initiated. Thats why you are getting the null pointer exception as the textview field is not being initiated.

There is a simple solution to your problem. The onProgressUpdate() method runs on the main UI thread and you have the access to the textview variable inside the onProgressUpdate() method. so simply do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
     MainActivity mainActivity =new MainActivity();

    for (String color : values) {

        textView.append(color + "\n");
    }
}
```